Single operator floor division
What programming languages other than Python has the floor division as a single operator from the programmers' point of view?
Why does it even exist? Please don't give me the answer of because it can!
I did google for it first but most results are just about accomplishing the same thing with combination of an operator and a function call. Duh!

Most languages do when called on integer operands. But I guess this isn’t the answer you’re looking for. — R has a dedicated operator very similar to Python (%/%).

@KonradRudolph Thank you but no, not the answer I am looking forward to.

@KonradRudolph I doubt most languages do. Can you name some?

@nocomment C, C++, C#, Java, etc. I should have qualified that by “most” I mean statically-typed languages. Most dynamically typed languages probably don’t do this.

@KonradRudolph How does it look in Java? I tried (-11) / 10 there and that gave -1, not -2.

@nocomment Oh that’s a really good point, I mentally replaced “floor division” with “integer division”, which obviously isn’t the same. Now I’m curious whether OP was really specifically interested in floor division as opposed to integer division.

Asking for a list of things isn't usually something we do here nor is it very productive. Do you have a more practical question that can be answered about this?

@deceze So far there is no list from the look of it. It is looking more like a none. Also the question of its existence is not answered at the time of posting this comment.

Here is the Python PEP that introduces the floor division operator // (so arguably the "most official Python document" on that topic): https://peps.python.org/pep-0238/ – it provides some rationale as to why the operator is introduced. Does this help you, or did you already find this?

As a bit of background information (I don't know how long you have been programming Python): Up to and including Python 2, division had different results depending on whether ints or floats were divided (e.g. 3/2 == 1 vs 3./2. == 1.5). This was a bit of a surprising behavior, given that Python usually doesn't care much about number types. Providing an explicit floor division operator helps resolving this: In Python 3, no matter whether ints or floats are given, / always provides true division. To keep Python 2's int division behavior, // can be used.

@KonradRudolph I meant one, not none. My bad.

@nocomment When I said two operators, I really meant operator and a function call. I edited the question.

@simon I think you should move the comment into an answer.

@KonradRudolph I think you should put %/% as an answer so that I can at least upvote it.

Here is a partial answer, addressing the 2nd part of the question – Why does [an explicit floor division operator //] even exist [in Python]? It is basically a summary of the relevant parts of PEP 238 in my words.
Up to and including Python 2.X, division with the division operator / had different results depending on whether values of integer types or floating point types were divided (e.g. 3.0/2.0 == 1.5; but 3/2 == 1 similar to integer division e.g. in C/C++, at least for positive numbers). This was a bit of a surprising behavior, given that Python usually doesn't care much about number types (e.g sqrt(2.0) == sqrt(2)). Moreover, in situations where the user of a piece of Python code had control over the input data types to a division, it was really tedious for the programmer of that piece of code to ensure that the intended division was used, which made it easy to produce a potential bug (e.g. if the programmer of a function implicitly expected float inputs and thus a "true" division, but the user of the function provided integers, the result could be plain wrong).
Thus, PEP 238 proposed a path for resolving this less than ideal situation, which was accepted into the Python language specification:

Starting from Python 2.2, an explicit floor division operator // was made available to always have the division behavior as if providing ints as input to the division. The division operator /, for the time being, kept is original (i.e. ambiguous/unintuitive) behavior. However, by using from __future__ import division on top of their module, programmers could already introduce a different behavior; namely, getting a "true" division with / within their module always, no matter whether ints or floats were given as input.
Starting from Python 3, no matter whether ints or floats are given, / now always provides "true" division. To keep Python 2's int division behavior, // can still be used.

As said, this is just the summary of the PEP in my words. For more information, I would suggest reading the original document that I linked above. It is really well-written and way more detailed. For example, it also discusses potential (rejected) alternatives on resolving the previous behavior of the / operator.
